# Getting error of "Top clause contains invalid value" on front end but in SQL Data is clearly visible

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

While binding data to Dataview getting this error but Parameters are correctly sending there values.

Seems DBhelper class is throwing this error but don't know why

My procedure:

```
   insert #leads(opp_lead,opp_NAME,CNT) 
select  opp_lead,'LEAD'+opp_lead,COUNT(*) from #pipeline GROUP BY opp_lead
UPDATE #leads SET opp_NAME=CONTACT_NAME FROM TBLCONTACT C,  #leads L WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),L.opp_lead)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),C.CONTACT_ID) 
COUNT(*) DESC
    create table #YearlyEndCampaign
       (
        slno INT ,  
           lvl int        
       )
SELECT TOP 1 @MAXLEADS=COUNT(*) FROM #pipeline   GROUP BY opp_lead ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC  

INSERT INTO #YearlyEndCampaign(slno,LVL)
    SELECT SEQ,0 FROM (SELECT TOP (@MAXLEADS) seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)  FROM [master]..spt_values)S
```

C# code:

```
long businessID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["BusinessID"]);
long YEAR = Convert.ToInt64(2015);    
long UserID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["Contact_ID"]);

BeggingDA objBeggingDA = new BeggingDA();          
DataView dv = (new BeggingDA()).BeggingLoadByBusinessID(YEAR, businessID, UserID);
```

Comment: It sql error, show your SP

Comment: How is your C# code related to the procedure at all? Also, if i search for the errormessage _"top clause contains invalid"_ i don't get any results. So what is the real message?

Comment: Whats the value of @maxlead?

Comment: Actually somehow TOP of @MAXLEADS is not getting any data but throwing only one line that TOP clause contains invalid value.

Comment: You can't get record that way. You have to create dynamic SQL query

Comment: can you please show me small example i'm new here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you say, the first `SELECT TOP 1 @MAXLEADS=COUNT(*) FROM #pipeline` statement is not returning any data. This means that `@MAXLEADS` is null.

If you then run `select top (NULL) FROM [master]..spt_values` you will get the `TOP clause contains an invalid value` error, because you are not passing a numeric value to `TOP`.

The solution is to check if `@MAXLEADS` is null before doing the insert - if there aren't any rows, you would be selecting top 0, so it is pointless doing the insert anyway. A simple `IF @MAXLEADS IS NOT NULL` should be sufficient:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @MAXLEADS=COUNT(*) FROM #pipeline   GROUP BY opp_lead ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC  

IF @MAXLEADS IS NOT NULL BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #YearlyEndCampaign(slno,LVL)
        SELECT SEQ,0 FROM (SELECT TOP (@MAXLEADS) seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)  FROM [master]..spt_values)S

END
```